# В JavaScript можно переменной назначить значение массива?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Только начал изучать JavaScript и наткнулся на не понятное мне чудо, или я что то не так делаю.

в общем суть в следующем:

```
var myAray = ["first","second"];
var myStr;
for (var i = 0; i < myAray.Length; i++) {
  myStr = myAray[i];
  alert(myStr);
}
```

В итоге получается undefined... В C#  такое работает(

пс: Дико извиняюсь за столько глупый вопрос!

Comment: Учи тщательней, в `JS` у массивов нет свойства `Length`, только `length`.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие,  да и ответ уже дан выше @Other

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вот надо же так,целый день думал что же со мной не так, все от шарпа не отойти)